# Creating a test that returns a sink

Tags: scala, akka

If I have a test where I want to mock the response from a Sink in akka-streams with the type:

```
Sink[String, Future[Integer]]
```

I would like to find a way to generate a default value of this type, but I have only found `Sink.empty[String]` which provides `String, Future[Done]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use `.fold` or `.foldAsync`:

```
val mockedFuture: Future[Integer] = ...

val sink: Sink[String, Future[Interger]] =
  Sink.foldAsync[Integer, String](0) { (int, string) =>  mockedFuture }
```

though it is difficult to understand what you mean by "default" here. You cannot mock `Sink`, so you have to pass some instance of it that does something. Should it ignore results? Aggregate them? Depending on answer you could also use:

- `Sink.head[String].mapMaterializedValue(_.map(stringToInteger))`
- `Sink.last[String].mapMaterializedValue(_.map(stringToInteger))`
- `Sink.fold[Future[Integer], String](Future.successful(0)) { (futureInt, strign) => future }`

or some other combination of `Sink.head`, `Sink.last`, `Sink.fold`, `Sink.foldAsync` or something else combined with `.mapMaterializedValue` to e.g. change `Future[Done]` to `Future[Integer]`.

It shouldn't be hard for you to figure that out if you have a decent IDE and an idea how exactly do you want to use this Sink in test.

Comment: For consuming all upstream elements and then completing `Sink.ignore().mapMaterializedValue(_ => Future.sucessful(whateveryouwant))` is probably a bit more clear than a value through fold for each element.